# Add a UIView before UINavigation

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4.2

I have created a navigation based application.

I need to add a UIView before the navigation with the company details and have user to click on a button to enter the UINavigation view.

How can i do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the UINavigation's `viewdidload` show a modal viewcontroller, and give the viewcontroller a button to dismiss it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add that UIView directly to the UIWindow, i.e. [self.window addSubview:self.myView]; and as you done with that UIView(after clicking on button), simply remove it from UIWindow and add UINavigationView to UIWindow.